# Error when building Ionic+Cordova hybrid app in Visual Studio

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

My project was running fine when I went to bed. Now I can't get past this error.

The command `"C:\Users\MY_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" prepare --platform Android --configuration Debug --projectDir . --projectName "aciIonic" --language "en-US"` exited with code 8.

I checked that all my paths were still set, and made sure everything was up to date in Android SDK manager.

I get a similar error when trying to build for iPhone, and for Windows Phone.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Have you tried using the ionic/cordova tools instead?

`ionic build android`

Comment: Yeah, the ionic cli seems to be working alright. I'd like to figure out why it stopped wokring in VS though so I can keep using ripple.

Comment: Could you email vscordovatools@microsoft.com with your output log and we can take it from there?

Comment: I fixed this problem by clearing my /bld/debug folder in project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior may sometimes show up if you move your project from one machine to the other or sometimes if your build is “corrupted” by some changes outside the VS environment.

In some cases, adding or overwriting certain files from outside Visual Studio often needs a clean or rebuild for VS to be able to detect changes completely. That could also have contributed to the error.

The resolution is to Rebuild or Clean the solution. Deleting the bld/ folder is the manual equivalent.